# How to get the the current hostname as the title of your terminal

Tags: unix, bash

I want to get the hostname of the remote system i connect to as the title of my terminal. I have a simple setting done in my bash_profile , which is populated in all the systems where i login.

I am using this script as of now

```
PS1='[\u@\h:\w]\$ '
export TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w \007\]'

# Terminal sets TERM_PROGRAM so we can tell it apart from regular VT100
case "$TERM_PROGRAM" in
"Apple_Terminal")PS1="$TITLEBAR$PS1"
esac
case "$TERM" in
"xterm")PS1="$TITLEBAR$PS1"
esac
# end insert
```

The problem is when i logout from a remote system , i am  not able to get my current system(hostname details) in the terminal title.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this one:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"'
```

add it in $HOME/.bash_profile on both local machine and remote machines.

Answer (score -1):

Make all of that a little bash function and then call that bash function manually when you logout of a remote system?

Comment: How do i do that . u mean i will have to create an alias cmd for logout . but how will i call these bash functions manually ?